# proof check product equals zero entails a multiplicand is zero

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing

Currently trying to learn/teach myself proofs, however I could use some feedback on this proof. just want to know if its correct. I am sure there is a much quicker way to prove this. My main concern is directed towards its correctness.
thank you

For all integers $a$ and $b$, if $ab=0$ and $a\neq0$, then $b=0$.

Suppose $ab=0$ and $a\neq0$.
By the trichotomy law there are 3 cases to consider for $b$.

Either $a<b$, $b<a$ or $a=b$

Case 1. Suppose $a<b$, and assume for a contradiction that $b\neq0$.

Thus either $0<b$ or $b<0$.

Case 1.1. Suppose $0<b$. Since $a<b$ we know that $a-b<0$.

So by the axiom of transitivity;

$a-b<b$ following this and applying the scaling axiom 
$ab-bb<bb$

applying scaling again we achieve
$aba-bba<bba$ which is $0<0$. A contradiction.

Note that whilst scaling by "$a$" we did not know whether $a<0$ or $0<a$, however the result remains the same.

Thus it is not the case that $0<b$.

Case 1.2. Suppose $b<0$. Since $a<b$ by transitivity $a<0$. 
From $a<b$ we get $a-b<0$.

Now applying scaling axiom we obtain.
$ab-bb>0$ so $–bb>0$

Applying scaling again we have $0<0$. A contradiction.
Thus it is not the case that $b<0$.

Since it’s the case that $b$ is neither greater nor less than zero, it must be that $b=0$. However this violates the initial supposition that $b\neq0$. An absurdity, thus $b=0$.

Therefore if $a<b$ then $b=0$.

Case 2. Suppose $b<a$ and assume for a contradiction that $b\neq0$.

… cases follow similarly to case 1…

Therefore, if $b<a$ then $b=0$.

Case 3. Suppose $a=b$.

Substituting this in for $ab=0$ we find $aa=bb=0$.

Further, it can be shown that $aab=a(0)=0=aa$. Therefore $a=0$.

This contradicts the initial assumption that $a\neq0$. Therefore $a\neq b$.
Now eliminating case 3 from trichotomy  leaves only cases 1 &2. Both cases imply that $b=0$.

Therefore if $ab=0$ and $a\neq 0$, then $b=0$.

UPDATE hey read your answer and tried to put a comment on but it would not post, so I am putting it here...
Hmm a little confused on why I would choose $a>0$ as my case 1 assumption. The reason I broke case 1 into 1.1 and 1.2 was to show for case 1.1 that if $b>0$ then $b<0$ (or some other contradiction) and similarly for 1.2. Which would then mean my assumption that $b \neq 0$ is contradicted. This would give me the required, if $a<b$ then $b = 0$. If I started with your assumptions for $a$ in these cases. I would be contradicting one of my primary assumptions.This would only then serve to eliminate the case $a<b$ similar to how I did my case 3. Is this what you are suggesting? Just want to make sure I am interpreting your solution correctly, otherwise good answer :)

Comment: I think you are assuming what you are trying to prove. You say, $aba−bba<bba \implies 0<0$, but why can you say this? Is it because, for example, $(ab)a = 0a$? $0a$ is not necessarily 0 since this is what you are trying to prove.

Comment: hmm i see your point, I also have a proof that a(0)=0 but i don't think that automatically entails the above theorem or does it? i assumed not and hence constructed the above proof.

Comment: I think case 1.1 is faulty and should be made parallel to case 1.2, which looks good. See my forthcoming answer for more.

Answer (score 1):

In general you have the right idea: break the problem down to cases and prove each case by axioms. You could use more detail in 1.2 to prove that $a(0) = 0$ and $b(0) = 0$. In case 3, instead of saying "it can be shown," just show it.

The main problem is that the proof is redundantly long. If we assume this axiom of the "scaling principle," we should be able to demonstrate the proof very briefly:

"Suppose $b ≠ 0$. Then (case 1) $a > 0 \implies ab > 0b$, by the scaling principle $\implies ab - 0b > 0 \implies a - 0>0$, which is a contradiction. Similarly for case 2 when $a < 0$".

Note that this uses roughly the same structure, axioms, and strategy as your proof. So why is yours so long? It seems to be because you are breaking the proof into cases based on the value of $a$ relative to $b$. You go to so much work to get to the relation $a - b<b$, while what you really need is $a<0$, which is where my proof starts.

To summarize: you are adding more conditions than you need. Remove them and your proof will be shorter, cleaner, and easier to evaluate.